# Erlang basic general server debugger output interpretation

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I'm having some trouble with an Erlang module. Here is the one that I wrote:

-module(basic_gen_server).
    -export([start/1, call/2, cast/2]).

```
start(Module) ->
    register(server, spawn(basic_gen_server,gen_server_loop,[Module, Module:init()])), server.

call(Pid,Request) -> 
    Pid ! {call, self(), Request},
    receive
        Reply -> Reply
    end.

cast(Pid,Request) ->
    Pid ! {cast, self(), Request},
    receive
        _ -> ok
    end.

gen_server_loop(Module, CurrentState) -> 
    io:fwrite("gen_server_loop~n", []),
    receive
        {call, CallPid, Request} -> 
            {reply, Reply, NewState} = Module:handle_call(Request,self(),CurrentState),
            CallPid ! Reply,
            gen_server_loop(Module, NewState);
        {cast, CastPid, Request} ->
            {noReply, NewState} = Module:handle_cast(Request, CurrentState),
            CastPid ! noReply,
            gen_server_loop(Module, NewState)
    end.
```

And here is the callback module that was defined:

```
% Written by Caleb Helbling
% Last updated Oct 10, 2014

-module(name_server).
-export([init/0, add/3, whereis/2, handle_cast/2,
         handle_call/3, handle_swap_code/1]).

%% client routines

add(ServerPid, Person, Place) ->
    basic_gen_server:cast(ServerPid, {add, Person, Place}).

whereis(ServerPid, Person) ->
    basic_gen_server:call(ServerPid, {whereis, Person}).

%% callback routines

init() ->
    maps:new().

handle_cast({add, Person, Place}, State) ->
    NewState = maps:put(Person, Place, State),
    {noreply, NewState}.

handle_call({whereis, Person}, _From, State) ->
    Reply = case maps:find(Person, State) of
        {ok, Place} -> Place;
        error -> error
    end,
    NewState = State,
    {reply, Reply, NewState}.

handle_swap_code(State) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

Upon trying to initialize the server with the following command:

```
MyServer = basic_gen_server:start(name_server).
```

I get the following debug output:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 29-Oct-2014::12:41:42 ===
Error in process <0.70.0> with exit value: {undef,[{basic_gen_server,gen_server_loop,[name_server,#{}],[]}]}
```

Conceptually, I understand the notion of making serial code into a basic server system, but I believe that I have a syntax error that I haven't been able to find using either syntax highlighting or Google. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: One remark not related to your question, I think you should remove the receive bloc in the gen_server cast interface. It causes the cast to be synchronous. just replace by ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `gen_server_loop` is not exported. So you can not call `basic_gen_server:gen_server_loop(Module, Module:init())`, which is what is happening inside  `spawn(basic_gen_server,gen_server_loop,[Module, Module:init()])`.

If you read your error message it tells you that function you are trying to call in undefined (trougn `undef` atom). Function being `{basic_gen_server,gen_server_loop,[name_server,#{}],[]}`, or where you have `{Module, Function, ListOfArgs, ...}`.  You always should check that

- there are no types module or function name
- function arity match number of arguments in call (List in error message)
- function is exported

All local calls (like `loop(SomeArgs)`, without module specified) will not compile if function is not defined.  And you can do local call dynamically (`FuntionName(SomeArgs)` again without module name).

---

**EDIT** after comment about need of local calls.

You actually could use lambda for this.  There is `spawn/1` funciton, which takes lambda (or `fun` if you like), so you can call `spawn( fun local_functino/0).`.  Only issue with that is fact that your `fun` can not take any arguments, but there is a way around it, with use of closures.

```
spawn(fun () ->
         gen_server_loop(Module, Module:init())
      end).
```

And `gen_serve_loop` stays local call.

Comment: I understand the use of exporting it, but our assignment explicitly wants us to just export certain functions in the program, namely start/1, call/3 and cast/2. Is there a way to avoid exporting the loop function, which is supposed to be hidden from the module interface?